# Which artifacts are uploaded by default gradle maven?

Tags: maven, gradle, archive

I cannot find in gradle docs which artifacts are uploaded by default. Is it so, that only compilation artifacts are uploaded? I have a case where I'm left with multiple jars in workspace after build process and I wanted to make sure that no garbage is uploaded.

I found info that in case of [multiple artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub:multiple_artifacts_per_project) I can define addFilter() but what about main artifact upload? How gradle determines which jar is uploaded by default?
I'd appreciate clear information and if someone could point me to documentation that I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot find in gradle docs which artifacts are uploaded by default

Gradle does not upload anything for you. You must configure whatever publishing plugin you are using with the artifacts you want published.

The official publishing plugins are:

- [Maven Publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)
- [Maven Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) (deprecated)

Neither of these plugins publish anything by default.

> I have a case where I'm left with multiple jars in workspace after build process

This is normal. However, if you are seeing artifacts that should not created, then you'll need to audit your Gradle build to see how that artifact is being created and disable it if needed.

There is (1) official Gradle plugin that I am aware of that does configure the above plugins to publish an artifact. This is documented on at the very bottom here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html

Comment: I checked how my jobs work and jar from build task is automatically added to uploadArtifacts, when I have more jars I can configure filter which could upload all jars e.g. `myApp*.jar`. According to what you wrote I have to look into other plugins in my project and check which one sets build jar as default artifact?

Comment: Other plugins and your project's Gradle configuration as a whole. Either a plugin is configuring publications or there is some logic in your Gradle files that has it.